# Getting empty dropdown in JSP

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, servlets

Here is the code. When I click the dropdown icon, it is empty. I want it to be loaded as soon as the page loads

```
ArrayList<Notifications> notifications = (ArrayList<Notifications>) session.getAttribute("notif");


  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Friend Requests">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </a>


                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                        <%
                            for(int i=0; i<notifications .size(); i++){
                        %>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><%= notifications .get(i).getSender() %></a>
                        </li>

                        <% } %>

                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: So whats the problem.. I find nothing wrong in your code.. It may be empty coz notifications might not have single entry.. `System.out` `notifications.size()` to verify

Comment: There are notfications. The size of arraylist is 3, i have checked it.

Comment: There are some typoes, but as you don't get any errors, this must not be the issue, for example `notifications .size()` extra space . or  `ArrayList<Notifications> notifications ` should be included in  `<%%>`. Else the code seems OK to me too, Try to move bootstrap htmls and see if it does not relay show it, May be bootstrap (css) hide them

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi there are no errors and it works fine with the static data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this simple sample :

```
<%
ArrayList<String> notifications = new ArrayList<String>();
notifications.add("One");
notifications.add("Two");
notifications.add("Three");

for(int i=0; i<notifications.size(); i++){
%>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><%= notifications.get(i).toString() %></a>
    </li>    
<%}%>
```

It works and print the Three letters. As I don't know your Notification object, I used an Array of String. Compare this with your code (May be you do not get complete array from session, or may be the `getSender` method does not return correct data.

Comment: Don't u think there is a problem with dropdown list ?

Comment: you are right, there was problem in database column-name due which my arraylist was empty. Thanks alot.